# How to speed up this Manipulate with Show?

Tags: manipulate, scoping

I'm doing this manipulation where there is a mapping between functions as follows. 
However, why does it not work when I substitute `{myfunc, colors, colors,  Range[Length@list], {c, (1 + 2 c)/3, 3 c, c^2, (1 + c)/2}}` with `{myfunc, colors, colors, Range[Length@list], list}`?
How could I speed up this code? 
The problem is that each curve is plotted separately and then combined with `Show`. 
It becomes slow when the number of functions increase and many formating options in each plot are added.
 Also the formating options overlaps because of `Show`so it is not easy to set up desired formating as you have to think about how many overlapping plots instead of just one.

```
func[t_] := (t^2 - 1)/3;
list = {c, (1 + 2 c)/3, 3 c, c^2, (1 + c)/2};
myfunc = func /@ list /. c -> t ;
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@list];

Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Show[
   MapThread[
    ReplaceAll[
       p_Point :> {p, 
         Text[Style[#4, 14], Offset[{5, 5}, p[[1]]], {-1, -1}]}]@
      Normal@Plot[#, {t, 0.5, 10}, Mesh -> {{#5}}, 
        MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize@Large, #2], PlotStyle -> #3, 
        GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large] &, {myfunc, 
     colors, colors, 
     Range[Length@list], {c, (1 + 2 c)/3, 3 c, c^2, (1 + c)/2}}]],
 {c, 1, 10, AnimationRate -> 1/3}]
```

[image]

Comment: what is `colors` ?

Comment: @Nasser thanks, I just added.

Comment: `It becomes slow when the number of functions increase`  Using the example you posted, I see no slow down. It runs fast when I move the slider. Using V 13. It is better to post an example that shows the actual issue in this case.

Comment: @Nasser it was slow so I removed all formating options and it is still slow. It probably due to my slow PC.

Comment: Well, it runs very fast for me. You can try this version I just made (will post it as answer then remove the answer when you copy it as easier than here in comment).

Comment: It would be better to show us a problem/failure than a successful example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others, I don't see poor performance in the example. However, one way to improve performance in general is to separate static computations from the dynamic ones.  For instance the plots do not change, just the points.  So separate out the plots and put the points inside their own `Dynamic[]`.  One other thing, `Manipulate` localizes control variables, so the OP's `c` inside `Manipulate` and the `c` inside `list` do not represent the same variable.  To fix this, one way is to use a different variable in `Manipulate` and substitute it in for `c`. The substitution may be done `expr /. c -> c0` or with `Block` as shown below.

```
func[t_] := (t^2 - 1)/3;
list = {c, (1 + 2 c)/3, 3 c, c^2, (1 + c)/2} ~
   Join~ (c*Range[0, 1, 1/10]);  (* add some extra functions *)
myfunc = func /@ list /. c -> t;
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@list];

Manipulate[
 Dynamic@
  Show[
   (*Beep[];*)  (* Beep[] gives evidence of non/reevaluation *)
   MapThread[
    Plot[#, {t, 0.5, 10}, PlotStyle -> #2, GridLines -> Automatic, 
      ImageSize -> Large] &, {myfunc, colors}],
   Graphics[
    Dynamic@
     Block[{c = c0},
      MapThread[
       With[{p = Point[{#5, #1 /. t -> #5}]},
         {PointSize@Large, #2, p, 
          Text[Style[#4, 14], 
           Offset[{5, 5}, p[[1]]], {-1, -1}]}] &, {myfunc, colors, 
        colors, Range[Length@list], list}]
      ]
    ]
   ],
 {{c0, 1, HoldForm[c]}, 1, 10, AnimationRate -> 1/3}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can copy and try this to see if it is faster.

```
func[t_] := (t^2 - 1)/3;
list = {c, (1 + 2 c)/3, 3 c, c^2, (1 + c)/2};
myfunc = func /@ list /. c -> t
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@list];

Manipulate[
 Show[MapThread[
   ReplaceAll[
      p_Point :> {p, 
        Text[Style[#4, 14], Offset[{5, 5}, p[[1]]], {-1, -1}]}]@
     Normal@Plot[#, {t, 0.5, 10}, Mesh -> {{#5}}, 
       MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize@Large, #2], PlotStyle -> #3, 
       GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large] &,
   {myfunc, colors, colors, 
    Range[Length@list], {c, (1 + 2 c)/3, 3 c, c^2, (1 + c)/2}}
   ]
  ],
 {c, 1, 10, AnimationRate -> 1/3},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c}
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it works okay. My computer is Win7-x64/8GB/no SSD, Corei5,3rdgen.

Regarding your query:

> why does it not work when I substitute {myfunc, colors, colors,
> Range[Length@list], {c, (1 + 2 c)/3, 3 c, c^2, (1 + c)/2}} with
> {myfunc, colors, colors, Range[Length@list], list}?

Wrap manipulate with `With`. See the color change for the `list=list`. You have to set `list` locally:

```
With[{list = list},
 Manipulate[
  Dynamic@
   Show[MapThread[
     ReplaceAll[
        p_Point :> {p, 
          Text[Style[#4, 14], Offset[{5, 5}, p[[1]]], {-1, -1}]}]@
       Normal@Plot[#, {t, 0.5, 10}, Mesh -> {{#5}}, 
         MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize@Large, #2], PlotStyle -> #3,
          GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large] &, {myfunc, 
      colors, colors, Range[Length@list], list}]], {c, 1, 10, 
   AnimationRate -> 1/3}]
 ]
```

Comment: I do not see why `Dynamic` is needed inside `Manipulate`. Manipulate itself is `Dynamic` module ? excessive use of `Dynamic` and in the wrong place can cause slow down if one is not careful. I try to use explicit `Dynamic` only when absolutely needed.

Comment: I agree; and thanks for bringing it up. The OP can explore `DynamicModule` as well.